# pyspark udf function storing incorrect data despite function producing correct result

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, user-defined-functions

So I have this weird issue.  I'm using a huge dataset that has dates and times in it represented by a single string.  This data can be easily converted using `datetime.strptime()`, but the problem is the data is so huge, I need to use pyspark to convert it.  No problem, I thought, I scoured stackoverflow and saw UDFs! so I made one.  unfortunately, the values stored in the dataframe don't match what the function actually produces.  I assumed a function would be executed row by row as spark sees the data, but it doesn't seem like that's happening.

Here's what I have (data is a pyspark dataframe called *result* and I'm showing the first 5 rows):

| timestamp | node_id | subsys | sensor | par | val_raw | val_hrf |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018/01/01 00:00:06 | 001e0610e532 | chemsense | lps25h | temp | -954 | -9.54 |
| 2018/01/01 00:00:30 | 001e0610e532 | chemsense | lps25h | temp | -954 | -9.54 |
| 2018/01/01 00:00:54 | 001e0610e532 | chemsense | lps25h | temp | -957 | -9.57 |
| 2018/01/01 00:01:18 | 001e0610e532 | chemsense | lps25h | temp | -961 | -9.61 |
| 2018/01/01 00:01:42 | 001e0610e532 | chemsense | lps25h | temp | -962 | -9.62 |

To convert the timestamp column into actionable data, I convert it to a float using a custom function:

```
def timeswap(x:str):
    print(x)
    utime= datetime.timestamp(datetime.strptime(x, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"))
    print(utime)
    return utime
```

I have confirmed this function works properly.  So I go ahead and run it on the entire column and decided to make a new column called unixTime to store it:

`timeUDF = spark.udf.register('timeUDF',timeswap,FloatType())  result_conv = result.withColumn('unixTime', timeUDF('timestamp'))`

Seems like it worked.  I spent weeks thinking this was accurate, running algorithms on the data only to find out recently the data is clumping in a way it shouldn't; multiple readings on a single date.  So I go ahead and tell spark to print the column.  Doing so actually causes the function to call for each row.  I new this would be a thing, so I put in the print statements as a sanity check: `result_conv.select('unixTime').head(5)`

It output this # comments by me:

```
2018/01/01 00:00:06 #The original string date
1514782806.0 #the correct output from the function
2018/01/01 00:00:30
1514782830.0
2018/01/01 00:00:54
1514782854.0
2018/01/01 00:01:18
1514782878.0
2018/01/01 00:01:42
1514782902.0
[Row(unixTime=1514782848.0), #I don't know what this value is
 Row(unixTime=1514782848.0),
 Row(unixTime=1514782848.0),
 Row(unixTime=1514782848.0),
 Row(unixTime=1514782848.0)]
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?  I've even confirmed that the float in the row list doesn't exist when running more than 5 lines, so I don't know where that value is arising from or why it's duplicating across rows.  It's neither the average nor the median value (and those shouldn't be used anyway), and I don't know why it's duplicating (the number of duplicates isn't consistent when I look at longer stretches of rows).  I'd really like to avoid having to convert this to a pandas DF, then back to a spark DF to do this.  Bottom line is I need to convert the date string into a unixtime float that is unique per line for this sensor (as it is in the data).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use UDFs. You can use inbuilt pyspark functions to do the same task. UDFs are the last resort. They slow down your program.

Here's what I did. I think the minor difference in value is due to timezone issues probably. Not sure though. If you better specify the problem, I could help further. E.g. `(1514745006 (my computer) - 1514782806 (your computer)) = 37800 seconds = 10.5 hours`. So it means you are 10.5 hrs ahead of my timezone.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext

sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
### This is very important setting if you want legacy behaviour
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy", "LEGACY")

data1 = [
    ["2018/01/01 00:00:06"],
    ["2018/01/01 00:00:30"],
    ["2018/01/01 00:00:54"],
    ["2018/01/01 00:01:18"],
    ["2018/01/01 00:01:42"],


]

df1Columns = ["time_col"]
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema=df1Columns)

# 1514782806.0  # the correct output from the function

df1 = df1.withColumn("integer_value", F.unix_timestamp(F.to_timestamp('time_col', 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss')))
df1.show(n=100, truncate=False)
```

Output :

```
+-------------------+-------------+
|time_col           |integer_value|
+-------------------+-------------+
|2018/01/01 00:00:06|1514745006   |
|2018/01/01 00:00:30|1514745030   |
|2018/01/01 00:00:54|1514745054   |
|2018/01/01 00:01:18|1514745078   |
|2018/01/01 00:01:42|1514745102   |
+-------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Thanks!  This worked.  I thought there might be functions to do this, but I wasn't sure.  I still don't know why the udf was duplicating values even though there were different dates, but that doesn't matter anymore!  I appreciate it!